# why jquery click function is not working inside foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysqli

My scenario is: creating button for each $newfrnd and when I click each button it insert a data in database(for example)

My question is : Button creation is happening fine. But it inserts data to database for each $newfrnd eventhough I am not clicking those $newfrnd buttons. 
I think there must be some logical problem in the second part of code, I tried many changes on that but its not working . everytime its inserting data as many time as the number of $newfrnd. Why click function is not working?

Kindly help

```
  <?php
            $newfrnd=$_SESSION['newarr'];
            foreach ($newfrnd as &$newfriend){
          ?>
            <input type="button" id="<?php echo $newfriend; ?>" value="<?php echo $newfriend; ?>"/>
          <?php
              }
          ?>
```

Inside Javascript/jquery inside document.ready

```
<?php
$newfrnd=$_SESSION['newarr'];
foreach ($newfrnd as &$newfriend) {
?>
$("#<?php echo $newfriend; ?>").click(function(){
    <?php
    mysqli_query($con,"Insert into friendlist values ('Friend8', '') ");
    ?>
});
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: **Future Caution:** Are you sure you want to give users the ability to insert data into the database with the click of a button? _(e.g. Is it possible that users could indefinitely click on the button?)_

Comment: This is ***not*** how PHP and JavaScript interact.  PHP runs on your *server*, its only job is to *generate* an HTML page (that may contain JavaScript and/or CSS).  That HTML page is then sent to your browser.  When rendered in your browser, PHP is *finished* and has stopped running.  You need to use AJAX to send a ***new*** request to PHP to add to the database.

Comment: Hi its for my oroject so no issueses with security.

Comment: Hey Rocket, Thanks for replying, I didn't get your point though. Isn't it click function for each button should work? if clicked then only its updating in database. Would you mind sharing few lines of code so that I can understand better

Comment: Read about web basics. Then do projects.

Comment: Its bad syntax - and bad programming. The javascript code inside the click method rendered is always going to be empty